# In Erlang, how do exits and errors interact with links, monitors, and system processes?

Tags: erlang

I'm getting a bit lost in Erlangs error handling.

- On one hand there are processes calling `exit(Reason)`, or `exit(Pid, Reason)`, or hitting a runtime error, or simply ending;
- and on the other hand there are linked processes, and monitoring processes, and system processes;
- and on the third hand what happens, or what message arrives, seems to depend on both of these variables.

Is there an overview of how these things combine, and what to expect in each case?

Comment: See "Programming Erlang 2nd" by Joe Armstrong.  The best way to learn any language is getting a good book and doing the exercises.  Reading a bunch of haphazard tutorials on the internet is not the way to go.

Comment: Hi @7stud, as it happens I'm working through that very book. It's a great book, isn't it! This question + self-reply tries to offer something I didn't get from book, Erlang docs, or Stack Overflow: an overview of the exit signal/message/behaviour for every combination of (a) exit signal causes, and (b) kind of signal recipient.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is structured as follows:

- 1. First, a brief overview of the three parts of an exit signal: cause, delivery, and handling.
- 2. Then a more detailed overview that goes through every combination of (kind of exit signal, kind of handler); explains how to send the signal; and explains how it will be received.
- 3. Finally, some examples that you can run in the shell.

#### 1. Overview of causes, delivery and handling of exit signals

Process exits happen all the time in Erlang. For example, a process might exit normally, which sends out an exit signal; and a monitor process then may receive that signal in the form of a message.

For another example, a process might exit with an error, and a linked process may receive an exit signal and exit with the same error.

This section summarizes the three sources of exits and exit signals, the two rules for who the signal is sent to, and the four things that may happen when an exit signal arrives.

##### 1.1 Where exit signals come from

- A process can exit normally, which automatically sends an exit signal with reason `normal`.
- A process can exit abnormally (including runtime errors and calls to `error/1`), which automatically sends an exit signal with a non-`normal` reason.
- A process can also manually send an exit signal without actually exiting.
- (Similar terminology, but unrelated: the Erlang Shell's [Job Control mode](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html#jcl-mode) has a `kill` command. But that does not kill processes, it kills Erlang shell jobs.)

##### 1.2 Who receives an exit signal

- When a process exits, an exit signal is sent to all linked and/or monitoring processes.
- When a process calls `exit(Pid, Reason)`, an exit signal is sent to process `Pid`.

##### 1.3 What happens when an exit signal arrives

- When an ordinary process receives an exit signal with reason `normal`, nothing happens.
- When an ordinary process receives an exit signal with a non-normal Reason, it exits with the same Reason. This causes another exit signal to its linkset processes.
- When a monitoring process would get an exit signal, instead it gets a message `{'DOWN', MonitorRef, process, Pid, Reason}`.
- When a system process would get an exit signal, instead it gets a message `{'EXIT', SendingPid, Reason}`. "System process" just means "traps exit signals, so cannot be killed by others". A process becomes a system process by calling `process_flags(trap_exit, true)`.

#### 2. Detailed overview: Every kind of exit signal, and every way it can be received

##### 2.1 Normal exits

How to achieve:

- your function returns/ends normally.
- call `exit(normal)`

Received as:

- by linked process: gets signal `{'EXIT', SenderPid, normal}`. Signal will be ignored.
- by system process: gets message `{'EXIT', SenderPid, normal}`.
- by monitoring process: gets message {'DOWN', Ref, process, SenderPid, normal}

##### 2.2 Abnormal exits

How to achieve:

- call `exit(Reason)`
- Runtime errors also cause an abnormal exit.

  - Call `error(my_error)`: if not caught, exit Reason will be `{my_error, Stack}`
  - Call `throw(my_ball)`: if not caught, exit Reason will be `{{nocatch, my_ball}, Stack}`
  - Hit a runtime error: if not caught, exit Reason will be
    `{ErrorReason, Stack}`. See https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html#exit-reasons
  - If you want to catch a runtime error, see the constructs `catch EXPR` and `try EXPR of MATCH_RESULT catch MATCH_ERROR`.

Received as:

- by linked process: gets signal `{'EXIT', SenderPid, Reason}`. Will itself die with `Reason`.
- by system process: gets message `{'EXIT', SenderPid, Reason}`.
- by monitoring process: gets message {'DOWN', Ref, process, SenderPid, Reason}

##### 2.3 Exit signal sent without exiting

How to achieve:

- call `exit(DestinationPid, Reason)` to send {'EXIT', SenderPid,
  Reason}. Originating process will continue to run!

Received as:

- by linked process: gets signal `{'EXIT', SenderPid, Reason}`. Will itself die with `Reason`.
- by system process: gets message `{'EXIT', SenderPid, Reason}`.
- by monitoring process: gets message {'DOWN', Ref, process, SenderPid, Reason}

#### 3. Examples

I will hopefully come back and add an example for every combination
above. For now, a few illustrations that you can run in the `erl` shell.
(The `flush()` call empties the process's queue and prints any
messages.)

##### 3.1 Process exits normally; our linked system process receives 'EXIT' message.

```
process_flag(trap_exit, true).
spawn_link(fun() -> rainbow end), timer:sleep(10), flush().
% Shell got {'EXIT',<0.95.0>,normal}
% ok
```

##### 3.2 Process exits abnormally; our linked system process receives 'EXIT' message.

```
process_flag(trap_exit, true).
spawn_link(fun() -> exit(goodbye) end), timer:sleep(10), flush().
% Shell got {'EXIT',<0.98.0>,goodbye}
% ok
```

##### 3.3 Process exits abnormally; our monitoring process receives 'DOWN' message.

```
spawn_monitor(fun() -> exit(im_a_teapot) end), timer:sleep(10), flush().
% {'DOWN',#Ref<0.2249327402.349700097.187011>,process,<0.80.0>,im_a_teapot}
% ok
```

##### 3.4 Process exits abnormally; a linked process dies, too.

```
Pid1 = spawn(fun() -> receive after 500 -> exit({self(), sneezed}) end end).
% <0.212.0>

{Pid2, Ref2} = spawn_monitor(fun() -> link(Pid1), receive after 1000 -> exit("all is well") end end).
% {<0.214.0>,#Ref<0.2249327402.349700097.187408>}

timer:sleep(600).
% ok

flush().
% Shell got {'DOWN',#Ref<0.2249327402.349700097.187408>,process,<0.214.0>,
             {<0.214.0>, sneezed}}
% ok

is_process_alive(Pid1).
% false

is_process_alive(Pid2).
% false
```

Comment: Note: I still need to add kill signals to this answer, if only because it's a special case of `exit/2`. For now: `exit(Pid, kill)` sends a kill signal, not an exit signal, to `Pid`. A kill signal cannot be trapped, not even by a system process. A killed process does an abnormal exit with reason `killed` (not `kill`).